# Issues in align image and download button in html and css

Tags: html, css

I have been created simple web page using html, css and some scripts.

Here is my jsfiddle i tried http://jsfiddle.net/67x8cyp9/12/

Html:

```
<div class="text-wrap"><img align="right" src="img/9780143332497.jpg"></div>
<div><form method="get" class="caption" action="9780143332497.jpg"><button type="submit">Download!</button></form></div>
```

May i know, how to place download button underneath of image?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

put the form div inside `.text-wrap` [Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/aashi/67x8cyp9/13/)

```
<div class="text-wrap">
   <img align="right" src="http://s2.postimg.org/8tyari0qx/9780143332497.jpg">
   <div>
      <form method="get" class="caption" action="9780143332497.jpg"><button type="submit">Download!</button></form>
   </div>
</div>
```